# A word to describe a situation where someone is proven wrong multiple times

Tags: single-word-requests

More specifically the person assumes that something was common knowledge but everyone he/she ask proves otherwise.  Initially the person asking makes fun of the people for not knowing.

Might be a stretch to ask, but who knows.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add a sample sentence to your question leaving the requested word as a "_____________".  Thanks! :-)

Comment: I tried thinking of a sentence, but it becomes nearly the same as the prompt I posted.

Comment: The problem is that without assigning a sentence part to the word (noun, adjective, etc.), you'll probably not end up with a word but with a phrase to, as your question states, "describe a situation".  Usually descriptions are more than one word so there might be some confusion about what you're really asking for.  A sentence would really help, such as "Once again, Joe's (assumptions, jumping to conclusions, etc.) made him the laughing stock among his chums".  Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: totally wrong, completely wrong , utterly wrong, cannot be more wrong...

Comment: outvoted. overruled. three strikes you're out. shot down in flames. blown out of the water.

Answer (score 1):

"Discredited" seems like a good word choice for the situation you appear to describe (a "know-it-all" who actually doesn't know "it" all).